# Use rules on custom content fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules

I am trying to apply a rule to a certain content type with a taxonomy term selected from a list, this term is from a select list that selects the terms from a certain vocabulary that lists the terms from the vocabulary. I want the rule to only apply when international is selected......I have been at if now for four days, nothing doing. Tried a search but the results I found were not helping. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can probably add a rule of this kind :

The event is : `Before saving content`
Restrict by type : `your content type`

Then add a condition : `Text comparaison` then select your field with the Data selection like this `node:field-example:0:name` and match the `International` value. The rules will fire if all theses conditions passes